# JS - Can't get constructor.name of instance of function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I have an instance(`bar`) of a function(`foo`), but `bar.constructor.name` returns `"Object"` instead of `"foo"`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
function foo(text){
    this.text = text;
}

foo.prototype = {
   getUppercase: function(){
      return this.text.toUpperCase();
    }
}

var bar = new foo("bar");
console.log(bar.constructor.name); //logs "Object" in Chrome
```

Comment: FWIW `bar instanceof foo` will return `true`. This may be a helpful alternative if checking the constructor's actual name isn't a hard requirement in this scenario.

Comment: @gfullam I didn't need to check if bar was an instance of foo, but just get a string with the constructor name of bar and store it somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *replace* the object on a function's `prototype` property, you have to take responsibility for fixing up the `constructor` property on it:

```
foo.prototype = {
  constructor: foo,                  // <====
  getUppercase: function() {
    return this.text.toUpperCase();
  }
};
```

It's not automatic. The only automatic population of that property is on the default object assigned to the function's `prototype` property when the function is originally created.

```js
function foo(text){
    this.text = text;
}

foo.prototype = {
  constructor: foo,
  getUppercase: function() {
    return this.text.toUpperCase();
  }
};

var bar = new foo("bar");
console.log(bar.constructor.name);
```

Alternately, *don't* replace the default object on `prototype`, just augment it (usually my preference):

```
foo.prototype.getUppercase = function() {
    return this.text.toUpperCase();
};
```

You can do multiple of those via `Object.defineProperties` or `Object.assign` (that latter may need a shim) or your own utility function.

---

Finally, I'd be remiss if I didn't call out a couple of things:

1. Overwhelmingly, constructor function names start with a capital letter in JavaScript. It *is* just a convention, but it's a very, very well-established convention.
2. In ES2015+, you can use `class` for a more concise version:
3. `Function#name` is new as of ES2015 and support is a bit sketchy as I write this in July 2016. (Chrome 51+ does indeed have it.)

FWIW:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    getUppercase(){
        return this.text.toUpperCase();
    }
}

var bar = new Foo("bar");
console.log(bar.constructor.name);
```

Of course, if you need to support older engines (like IE11), you need to transpile if you do that... (But then again, if you're using `Function#name`, that's from ES2015 too.)

Comment: I've read about classes in Javascript. I think I'm not going to use it as I want to support older versions of IE, but thanks (again) for your answer.

Comment: @qwertytrewq: No worries, glad to help. Beware of using `Function#name` (that was probably just an example for your question, though, I'm guessing), as it's also new (and not supported in IE11).

Comment: I haven't seen the notation `Function#name` before. Why not refer to it as `Function.name` with a dot instead of a hash mark?

Comment: @gfullam: The `#` is a convention in JS circles (and I think it's bled over into some others as well) for "a member of instances, possibly via the prototype chain". The property `Function.name`, literally, has the value `"Function"` (on a compliant ES2015+ engine). `Function#name` (or `Object#toString`, or `Date#getdays`, etc.) is used to indicate the property isn't on the constructor (`Function`, `Object`, `Date`), but rather the prototype assigned to instances (or in some cases, a property directly assigned to instances).

Comment: Thanks. Now, I know. :)